# ASP.NET API Project, Microsoft Identity Platform configuration gives error: Unrecognized command or argument '--code-update=true'

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-identity-platform

In Visual Studio, I'm trying to configure an ASP.NET Web API project to be published to the Azure cloud. Authentication will be done through the Microsoft Identity Platform. Currently,  this is not configured in the project's publishing settings:

[image]

Clicking "Configure" pulls up a dialog box where I complete a series of simple config steps. At the end, the dialog seems to execute a number of tools/utilities to put in place the settings I just specified. One of these commands it attempts to run is failing:

```
Inserting code...

dotnet msidentity --update-project --tenant-id [OUR TENANT ID] --username [MY USERNAME] --client-id [OUR CLIENT ID] --project-file-path "[OUR PROJECT PATH].csproj" --calls-graph=True --calls-downstream-api=True --code-update=true --json

Unrecognized command or argument '--code-update=true'
```

I'm not sure what to do about this, as all these commands are being generated and executed internally. I have the latest version of the Azure.Identity (1.5.0) and Microsoft.Identity.Web (1.21.1) NuGet packages installed. All other Nuget packages are up to date as well.

Any pointers on how I can try to debug this?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this one? I am down that rabbit hole?  I also suspect it is a mismatch between the cli tool and the VS tooling... not sure

Comment: @GlennFerrie I WAS! I didn't realize I hadn't posted it as an answer here. See the answer now posted below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find help and get an answer by posting on the Visual Studio support site:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/aspnet-api-project-microsoft-identity-platform-con/1627164

It turns out there are a separate set of packages- besides both NuGet and the standard install of .NET- which I was completely unaware of: "local CLI tools". Specific versions of certain command line tools were created as part of the VS project, and these versions were in fact out of date and so created a conflict with the newer code from NuGet.

Using the .NET CLI, I ran the command `dotnet tool uninstall` on all local packages for the project, which effectively tells the project to just use the version of the tool present in the current install of the .NET framework, rather than a specific version from a local copy. This fixed the problem.

Comment: Great response.  I will give it a try.  that makes sense.